# How to perform operations on union of array types?

Tags: typescript

The following doesn't work

```
type Foo = number[]
type Bar = string[]

function move(x: Foo | Bar) {
    const v = x.splice(0, 1)
    x.splice(1, 0, ...v)
}
```

Because apparently `v` is `number[] | string[]` and is not assignable to either number or string. How do I work around this?

Comment: Does this really need to be limited to just these two types of arrays? If you want to use generic array operations, it makes more sense to just make the function accept `unknown[]` (as the type doesn't matter) or a generic (if you want to be able to specify a type).

Comment: I can make it a generic, but then I can't pass a value of type `number[] | string[]` to that generic function. These are different types of objects in my store, they all have an array of something that needs to be moved. I can make it check the `type` field on the store object, but then the code is not extensible and I have to modify it every time I add a new object type.

Comment: @VLAZ `unknown[]` works though, guess I'll stick with that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Use `unknown` if the type does not matter

Since this is a completely generic operation on an array (moving some elements), the actual type of the array is irrelevant. It is enough to declare that the function accepts any array where `unknown[]` or `Array would work:

```typescript
type Foo = number[]
type Bar = string[]

function move(x: unknown[]) {
    const v = x.splice(0, 1)
    x.splice(1, 0, ...v)
}

declare const arr: Foo | Bar;
move(arr); //OK
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKA7ArgWwEYQE4DaAugLABQokUAQgIZ7JQDOweAlqgObHnkBm6VAGNgbOKiiY4ANwgAKAB4AuKIIDWqOAHdUxAJRQA3uSimoQ8SyjTGCgHRMwAGzZD5ABgA0UAIx6TZvaOLm5yPt5eUHbR0v5kAL68ZAAmEEJO9NAWqFb0eCrwiAA+NPQA3ORSsnJ5emVQAPQNAPIA0kA)

### Use a generic if the type may matter

If it makes sense to also include the type, use a generic and constrain it to only arrays:

```typescript
type Foo = number[]
type Bar = string[]

function move<T extends Array<unknown>>(x: T) {
    const v = x.splice(0, 1)
    x.splice(1, 0, ...v)
}

declare const arr: Foo | Bar;
move(arr); //OK
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKA7ArgWwEYQE4DaAugLABQokUAQgIZ7JQDOweAlqgObHnkBm6VAGNgbOKiiY4ANwgAeACpQIAD2ARUAEyZQAgnjy0QcwQGtUcAO6oAfDYAUKgFxQFASigBvclF9Qh4ixQ0owqAHRMYAA2bEIQ9gAMADRQAIxuPn7hkTFx9qkpyVBhJdIZZAC+vGSaEEJR9NABqEH0eC7wiAA+NPQA3ORSsvZtbn1QAPQTAPIA0kA)

This might be useful to specify the types expected in a call which will then raise a compilation error if they do not match:

```typescript
move<string[] | number[]>(arr);             // OK
move<string[] | number[] | boolean[]>(arr); // OK
move<string[] | boolean[]>(arr);            // error
move<string[]>(arr);                        // error
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=30&pln=14&pc=53#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKA7ArgWwEYQE4DaAugLABQokUAQgIZ7JQDOweAlqgObHnkBm6VAGNgbOKiiY4ANwgAeACpQIAD2ARUAEyZQAgnjy0QcwQGtUcAO6oAfDYAUKgFxQFASigBvclF9Qh4ixQ0owqAHRMYAA2bEIQ9gAMADRQAIxuPn7hkTFx9qkpyVBhJdIZZAC+vGSaEEJR9NABqEH0eC7wiAA+NPQA3NVSsnIs7FzEUD0YOPjEDm1ufX7LK1AA9GtQAPIA0uRD8qMc3ESTaFi4hKc92AhRELSoc-YLSxvbe2QHI6zHEzd3B5PIjzAyLVard74PBwPD7GSHX7jEEvMFLCEYjFQgywoA)